# Tomcat7 ignores java.util.logging in logging.properties

Tags: java, logging, tomcat7, apache-shindig

My tomcat7/shindig instance is completely ignoring the config in logging.properties file. I have the following specified ./WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler,java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.prefix=shindig-errors.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.directory=/var/log/tomcat7/
```

However no files appear /var/log/tomcat7/ and logs are not appended. What am I missing?

I know using log4j is 'recommended' approach but I'm trying to get visibility on shindig classes that log using java.util.logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing [java.util.logging.FileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) properties with [org.apache.juli.FileHandler](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/FileHandler.html) properties.  Change the package name of the FileHandler in your logging.properties file.